# more idiomatic swift test for optionset?

Tags: swift, optionsettype

Still getting used to the use of `OptionSetType` in Swift.

In good ol' C, if I had something like

```
typedef enum {
    CHAR_PROP_BROADCAST          =0x01,
    CHAR_PROP_READ               =0x02,
    CHAR_PROP_WRITE_WITHOUT_RESP =0x04,
    CHAR_PROP_WRITE              =0x08,
    CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY             =0x10,
    CHAR_PROP_INDICATE           =0x20,
    CHAR_PROP_SIGNED_WRITE       =0x40,
    CHAR_PROP_EXT                =0x80
} CharacteristicProperty;
```

I could test a set of flags with something simple like:

```
if ((propertiesMask & (CHAR_PROP_NOTIFY | CHAR_PROP_INDICATE)) != 0) ...
```

The Swift alternative might look like

```
let properties:CBCharacteristicProperties = [.Write, .Read, .Indicate]
!properties.intersect([.Indicate, .Notify]).isEmpty
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this test? Not a fan of the ! out front. But otherwise, seems straightforward enough, except I'm really interested in when there IS an intersection. This led me to want to add my own.

```
extension OptionSetType {
    func hasIntersection(other:Self) -> Bool {
        return !self.intersect(other).isEmpty
    }
}
```

Which then allows me to write

```
properties.hasIntersection([.Indicate, .Notify])
```

Is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this? Did I roll my own and miss something?

Comment: To avoid the `!` you could do `properties.intersect([.Indicate, .Notify]).count > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this method from the protocol `SetAlgebraType` which `OptionSetType` implements:

> [isDisjointWith(_: Self) -> Bool](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SetAlgebraType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SetAlgebraType/s:FPs14SetAlgebraType14isDisjointWithFxSb)
>
> Returns true iff self.intersect(other).isEmpty.

So you could shorten your test to:

```
!properties.isDisjointWith([.Indicate, .Notify])
```

or

```
properties.isDisjointWith([.Indicate, .Notify]) == false
```

You can also compare the raw values with bitwise operators, just as you would do in C:

```
(properties.rawValue & (CharacteristicProperties.Notify.rawValue | CharacteristicProperties.Indicate.rawValue)) != 0
```

Full example code (in a playground):

```
struct CBCharacteristicProperties : OptionSetType {
  let rawValue: UInt
  init(rawValue: UInt) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

  static let Broadcast          = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x01)
  static let Read               = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x02)
  static let WriteWithoutResp   = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x04)
  static let Write              = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x08)
  static let Notify             = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x10)
  static let Indicate           = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x20)
  static let SignedWrite        = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x40)
  static let Ext                = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue:0x80)
}

let properties = CBCharacteristicProperties([.Write, .Read, .Indicate])
print(!properties.intersect([.Indicate, .Notify]).isEmpty)
print(!properties.isDisjointWith([.Indicate, .Notify]))
print(properties.isDisjointWith([.Indicate, .Notify]) == false)
print((properties.rawValue & (CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify.rawValue | CBCharacteristicProperties.Indicate.rawValue)) != 0)
```

result:

```
"true"
"true"
"true"
"true"
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution I found most appealing in the end was to simply add the following extension:

```
extension SetAlgebraType {
    var notEmpty:Bool {
        return self.isEmpty.NOT
    }
}
```

This allowed me to write code:

```
if properties.intersect([.Indicate, .Notify]).notEmpty {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the member `NOT`? It's on a `Bool` value and, to my knowledge, no such member exists.

Comment: Another one of my own extensions. Sorry :(

Comment: I suspected it might be. No need to be sorry, I was just curious.